# How to create high altitude clouds? (cirrus and cirrocumulus)

Tags: shaders, volumetrics, procedural, world

Pretty much all cloud tutorials show how to make *Cumulus* clouds, or some random blob of a cloud, but I'm looking to create high altitude clouds, which you can see below.

[image]

I'm most interested in the *cirrus* and *cirrocumulus* clouds, of which you can see some bigger pics below.

[image]

Any way to create these as a procedural volume material or as a world shader perhaps?
I *would* prefer a volumetric material though, as I need a transparent background behind the clouds, and lighting in the scene to affect the clouds.

Comment: I have found these higher cloud formations are a good place to back away from volumetrics and rely on the world shader.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I still need them to react to lighting. In either case, if you could help either way, I'd be very grateful, as I haven't managed to get realistic results.

Comment: I haven't tried [this free addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/procedural-cloudscape-generation-in-cycles-now-eevee/694700/4) but Simon Thommes' work is usually worth investigating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the best looking volumetrics you needs to increase the *Max Bounces* for *Volume* as well as look at the settings under *Volumes* a few panes down.

Also worth noting make sure your *Principled Volume* is set to pure white.

[image]

The optimal settings here will depend on the size of your object, for example in my scene a fairly large object renders like this with the above settings.

[image: 1024 samples clouds low quality settings]

By decreasing the *Step Rate* you slow down the ray as it passes through the volume and allow for more accurate detection of the edges of the volume.  It's essentially the same as increasing the number of volume slices in Eevee, but for Cycles rays.

Increasing the max steps is maybe not necessary, but... it's an option.  Using these settings we produce this image from the same volume.

[image: 1024 samp high quality settings]

Fairly detailed, reactive to light, but the downside is render time.

Here's the node group I used to make this:

[image]

Wave texture seems particularly suited to making an array of clouds if you spend enough time messing with *Detail Scale* and *Detail Roughness*.  Be sure to turn *Detail* up to 4 or higher but beware of performance considerations.

[image]

I'm sure with some masking and modifications you can get close to some of these formations.  I'm completely lost on how to achieve the swoosh shape right now, but hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: I apologize if the images are a little hard to see on some screens.  On my main monitor it wasn't that hard to distinguish.

Comment: Not problem, and thanks. It's a start, but it still needs lots of work to approximate those clouds.

Answer (score 2):

This reply might be a bit late, but I figured out a way to at least approximate cirrus clouds using purely volumetric modeling with noise and gradient textures.  To begin, I tabbed into Edit mode and scaled the default cube by 4 on X and Y, leaving it at 1 on Z (final dimensions are 8 x 8 x 2, but the scale is still 1 — make sure to apply scale if it isn't 1).  Then I applied the material setup pictured below.

[image]

If you then add a plane, give it a hair particle system with a low number of particles, choose the cube as the render object, choose a scale of 1, and give it appropriate rotation and rotation randomization. This gives you a field of cirrus clouds.  Paired with the Physical Starlight and Atmosphere addon for the sky and sunlight, it looks like this in EEVEE (with best volumetric tile size of 2 px):

[image]

Obviously, more work is needed to finesse them and give them some more random variation, but it's at least a start.  I'll update with any further improvements I make.